# Selenium python auto click

Tags: python, selenium

Hi guys I have some trouble.
When I use this on autoclick :

```
action=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
action.click() or action.submit()
```

So what is my problem. When script write in python automatically click on submit it's passed by no advert will be added on web ,but when I click manual it's passed and advert will be added on web. I dont know where is problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are *multiple submit buttons* on the page. Make a more specific locator:

```
action = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#formpridani input[type=submit]")
actions.click()
```